# How to define set in coq without defining set as a list of elements

Tags: set, coq

I am trying to define (1,2,3) as a set of elements in coq. I can define it using list as (1 :: (2 :: (3 :: nil))). Is there any way to define set in coq without using list.

Comment: Do finite sets suffice? Or do you mean for a more general definition of sets?

Comment: Define set of elements not implemented as list

Comment: @Amit this looks like a homework question. My guess is that your teacher wants you to use the first encoding in my answers, namely, sets as functions `T -> Prop`.

Answer (score 19):

The are basically four possible choices to be made when defining sets in Coq depending on your constraints on the base type of the set and computation needs:

- If the base type doesn't have decidable equality, it is common to use:

  ```
  Definition Set A := A -> Prop
  Definition cup A B := fun x => A x /\ B x.
  ...
  ```

  basically, Coq's [Ensembles](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Sets.Ensembles.html). This representation cannot "compute", as we can't even decide if two elements are equal.
- If the base data type has decidable equality, then there are two choices depending if extensionality is wanted:

  - Extensionality means that two sets are equal *in Coq's logic* iff they have the same elements, formally:

    ```
    forall (A B : set T), (A = B) <-> (forall x, x \in A <-> x \in B).
    ```

    If extensionality is wanted, sets should be represented by a canonically-sorted duplicate-free structure, usually a list. A good example is Cyril's Cohen [finmap](https://github.com/Barbichu/finmap) library. This representation however is very inefficient for computing as re-sorting is needed every time a set is modified.
  - If extensionality is not needed (usually a bad idea if proofs are wanted), you can use representations based on binary trees such as Coq's [MSet](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.MSets.MSets.html), which are similar to standard Functional Programming set implementations and can work efficiently.
- Finally, when the base type is finite, the set of all sets is a finite type too. The best example of this approach is IMO math-comp's [finset](http://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.finset.html), which encodes finite sets as the space of finitely supported membership functions, which is extensional, and forms a complete lattice.

Comment: Why is Cyril's Cohen finmap inefficient?

Comment: A bit informally, the reason is because of the extensional representation. A `{fset T}` needs to be "sorted" every time is modified. On top of that, the "sorting" function is extremely inefficient as it will enumerate all possible lists until it gets the desired one. This helps to avoid having to equip `T` with an order relation, as choice is guaranteed to be extensional on the predicate (in this case, the library picks the first list satisfying, P x := perm_eq x (undup s) IIRC), which implies extensionality.

Comment: Regarding your last bullet (base finite type) are you aware of any more lightweight implementations besides `finset`? It is a part of `sslreflect` which is a heavy dependency, which in addition comes with it's own language....

Comment: Well, you have Robbert Krebbers' https://gitlab.mpi-sws.org/robbertkrebbers/coq-stdpp , but I am not sure it is more "lightweight" , YMMV. ssreflect is surprisingly lightweight for the power it packs.

Answer (score 7):

The standard library of coq provides the following finite set modules:

1. [`Coq.MSets`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.MSets.MSets.html) abstracts away the implementation details of the set. For instance, there is [an implementation that uses AVL trees](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.MSets.MSetAVL.html#) and [another based on `list`s](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.MSets.MSetList.html#).
2. [`Coq.FSets`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.FSets.FSets.html) abstracts away the implementation details of the set; it is a previous version of `MSets`.
3. [`Coq.Lists.ListSet`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.ListSet.html) is an encoding of lists as sets, which I am including for the sake of completeness

Here is an example on how to define a set with `FSets`:

```
Require Import Coq.Structures.OrderedTypeEx.
Require Import Coq.FSets.FSetAVL.

Module NSet := FSetAVL.Make Nat_as_OT.
(* Creates a set with only element 3 inside: *)
Check (NSet.add 3 NSet.empty).
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many encodings of sets in Coq (lists, function, trees, ...) which can be finite or not. You should have a look at Coq's standard library. For example the 'simplest' set definition I know is [this one](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Sets.Ensembles.html)